# How to get info about last called func in Go?

Tags: go, runtime, stack-trace

Is it possible to get name of the last called function and args that were passed to?

```
func main() {
    f(1)
    log.Printf("%s(%s=%d)", // how to paste here "f(arg=1)"? )
}

func f(arg int) {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

> Is it possible to get name of the last called function and args that were passed to?

No.